# SolusVM with KVM and HVM disk limits

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualization, solusvm

I have searched google and also asked SolusVM directly in a ticket just now. I cant seem to find the answer anywhere.

Im curious what the max disk space of KVM and also HVM vps units is?

I have a customer that wants to setup a node with one vps having a 2tb disk. I just dont know if this is possible and will be stable.

Its going to be an email server so I dont want it to crash and then loose everything because it couldnt handle the size. But I myself have never gone above 300gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVM can handle virtual disks of any size so there would be no trouble creating either a raw or qcow based disk of 2TiB is size. You can actually create a qcow2 file with a virtual size of 2^63 bytes but you will find tools inside the VM will not cope (fdisk under Linux will simply crash out back to the command prompt) so the limit is what the guest OS can deal with not what KVM can provide to it. Of course you need to make sure the host filesystem has the room needed and can deal with large files for when the VM does try to use terabytes of space but everything modern can (just don't try it with dos/FAT!).

Comment: Does this also go for hvm or just kvm?

Comment: I have no experience with Xen specifically so I don't know. My assumption is that it would be similar.